# How to Get Message_id from sent message By BOT Telegram?

Tags: php, telegram-bot

I program the `bot` telegram.

I want Get `message_id` By Bot ,when I sent a message to Group.

My Code is `PHP`.

```
$token = "MY_BOT's_TOKEN";

$data = [
    'text' => 'my message here',
    'chat_id' => 'the_chat_id_here'
];

file_get_contents("https://api.telegram.org/bot$token/sendMessage?" . http_build_query($data) );
```

How Do it?

best regard.

Comment: share some of your code and specify which library you are using.

Comment: i changed my answer.

Comment: i am not expert in php, but follow these steps:
$response =file_get_contents("https://api.telegram.org/bot$token/sendMessage?" . http_build_query($data) );
echo $response;

now you know the structure of the json response, then write a code to parse the json result and to extract the messageID.

Comment: I Do it.But noting return.it is empty.
```$result=$this->send_message ( $data );```

Comment: why don't you use these well coded APIs?
https://github.com/unreal4u/telegram-api
https://github.com/php-telegram-bot/core
if you use these libraries, you won't need to handle connection issues. and you also won't need to somehow invent the wheel again.

Comment: thanks . I try work by that link,

Comment: Mr @tashakori your answer is correct.when massage has been send ,return result message.has {ok="",message_id}

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your file_get_contents call returns a result containing status code and messageId.

```
$result = file_get_contents("https://api.telegram.org/bot$token/sendMessage?" . http_build_query($data) );
```